# Run on list that passed as void* data

Tags: c++, list, reference

I sent a list of type "Albums" to a callback function of SQL database.
I tried to run on the list with for loop but I got an error that says "This range-based 'for' statement requires a suitable "begin" function and none was found"
Here is my code:

```
//my code in short
int callbackPictures(void* data, int argc, char** argv, char** azColName)
{
    list<Album>* albums = static_cast<list<Album>*>(data);
    for (auto& album : albums)//this is where I got the error
    {
     //do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: `albums` is a pointer, so you want to dereference it first: `for (auto& album : *albums)`. But I'm not quite sure if the lifetime of `*albums` will be correct.

Comment: Thank you very much it worked